# CodeIgniter route handling for admin and client apps

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

**Folders Structure:**

I have two apps in my application folder:
application/admin And
application/client

And two index files in the codeigniter root directory:
index.php ( for client app ) And
admin.php ( for admin app )

**.htaccess rules:**

Rule for index.php (client)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Rule for admin.php (admin)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)*$ admin.php/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Issue:**

There is issue in admin part. 
When i write URL like
**http://localhost/sandbox/admin/admin-controller-name**

its route to admin app but the URL structure become like 
**http://localhost/sandbox/admin.php/admin-controller-name**

**I want to display my admin URL like**
**http://localhost/sandbox/admin/admin-controller-name**

Comment: what comes on here **admin-controller-name**

Answer (score 0):

In `routes.php`

```
$route['admin/admin-controller-name'] = 'admin';
```

---

In here

`$route['admin/admin-controller-name']` we define how URL look like
`= 'admin'` This actually path of your Controller

Comment: For this URL admin/admin-controller-name 
Then .htaccess following rule become true
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)*$ admin.php/$1 [R=301,L]

and then the url become
admin.php/admin-controller-name 

I want to remove the .php, just show admin

Comment: give me example URL what you expect as answer

Comment: My url should display like this 
http://localhost/admin/controller/method
instead of 
http://localhost/admin.php/controller/method

There are two apps in my application folder
application/client
application/admin

admin.php is index file for admin app
and
index.php is a index.file for client app
both files are in root directory

Comment: So define your cotroller inside `admin` folder. In ther oastr your controller. So it will show as yours

Comment: i have controllers in my admin controller folder lets say dashboard controller
it redirects to dashboard controller but the url is display this one 
localhost/admin.php/dashboard/index

Comment: Remive your htaccess and place first one in your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95018/discussion-between-masood-rehman-and-abdulla).